# For Loop for Moving Files

Tags: windows, batch-file

**Hi Mates,**

I am using below mentioned codes for the movement of files.

It is moving the files but it iterates for no of times equal to the no of files which are being moved to other folder. Please suggest so that all files would move but it doesnt show on screen about multiple iterations.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=_." %%i IN ('DIR /b C:\Hi\*_*.*') DO (
ECHO %%i
move C:\Hi\*.pdf E:\%%i
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: I have done it :) Code has been given below.
                                                                                                                                                            

    @echo off

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


    if exist C:\Hi\*.pdf (goto COPYFILES) else (goto NOFILES)

    :COPYFILES
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=_." %%i IN ('DIR /b C:\Hi\*_*.*') DO (
    ECHO %%i
    move C:\Hi\*.pdf E:\%%i

    if NOT exist C:\Hi\*.pdf goto :NOFILES

    )

    :NOFILES
    echo There are no files to move
 


    PAUSE

Answer (score 0):

I have done it :) Code ha

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


if exist C:\Hi\*.pdf (goto COPYFILES) else (goto NOFILES)

:COPYFILES
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=_." %%i IN ('DIR /b C:\Hi\*_*.*') DO (
ECHO %%i
move C:\Hi\*.pdf E:\%%i

if NOT exist C:\Hi\*.pdf goto :NOFILES

)

:NOFILES
echo There are no files to move



PAUSE
```